# How do Clojure futures and promises differ?

Tags: clojure, terminology, future, promise

Both futures and promises block until they have calculated their values, so what is the difference between them?

Comment: I'm not sure why the -1 on the question, or are questions where you don't know the answer before asking now bad things?

Comment: I did not -1 any of the answers?? How can we tell who has put -1 on a quesiton or answer?

Comment: You and I can't, Zubair.  I'm just curious who put a -1 on your question given that it's a perfectly reasonable question to ask and it's definitely on-topic for SO.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Answering in Clojure terms, here are some examples from [Sean Devlin's screencast](http://www.vimeo.com/8320428):

```
(def a-promise (promise))
(deliver a-promise :fred)

(def f (future (some-sexp)))
(deref f)
```

Note that in the promise you are explicitly delivering a value that you select in a later computation (`:fred` in this case).  The future, on the other hand, is being consumed in the same place that it was created.  The `some-expr` is presumably launched behind the scenes and calculated in tandem (eventually), but if it remains unevaluated by the time it is accessed the thread blocks until it is available.

---

***edited to add***

To help further distinguish between a promise and a future, note the following:

#### promise

1. You create a `promise`.  That promise object can now be passed to any thread.
2. You continue with calculations.  These can be very complicated calculations involving side-effects, downloading data, user input, database access, other promises -- whatever you like.  The code will look very much like your mainline code in any program.
3. When you're finished, you can `deliver` the results to that promise object.
4. Any item that tries to `deref` your promise before you're finished with your calculation will block until you're done.  Once you're done and you've `deliver`ed the promise, the promise won't block any longer.

#### future

1. You create your future.  Part of your future is an expression for calculation.
2. The future may or may not execute concurrently.  It could be assigned a thread, possibly from a pool.  It could just wait and do nothing.  From your perspective *you cannot tell*.
3. At some point you (or another thread) `deref`s the future.  If the calculation has already completed, you get the results of it.  If it has not already completed, you block until it has.  (Presumably if it hasn't started yet, `deref`ing it means that it starts to execute, but this, too, is not guaranteed.)

While you **could** make the expression in the future as complicated as the code that follows the creation of a promise, it's doubtful that's desirable.  This means that futures are really more suited to quick, background-able calculations while promises are really more suited to large, complicated execution paths.  Too, promises seem, in terms of calculations available, a little more flexible and oriented toward the promise creator doing the work and another thread reaping the harvest.  Futures are more oriented toward automatically starting a thread (without the ugly and error-prone overhead) and going on with other things until you -- the originating thread -- need the results.

Comment: But you can have any caluclation block until either a promise OR a future is finished . ie: (@a + @b) will work the same with both a future and a promise

Comment: A promise allows for more flexibility it looks like to me.  I create a promise.  I pass that promise to another thread.  I can then do lots of complicated calculations including waiting for I/O, downloading data from the Internet, waiting for user input, etc.  When it's all done, I deliver the promise with the resulting value.  A future covers one S-expression.  It could, I guess, be a very, very complicated S-expression, but it would be a bit ... rigid there.  In addition a future does its work automatically in a thread (or pool).  To do the same in a promise would mean even more work.

Comment: FWIW since a single s-expression can be a call to an arbitrary code path, it's not necessarily about how much code you can cram into the expression.  So instead of saying a promise is "more flexible", I'd say it's purpose is simply different.  Otherwise, why have both?

Comment: Just for the record, the body of a `future` call can include N sexprs.

Comment: This explanation should be part of Clojure Doc

Answer (score 27):

Both Future and Promise are mechanisms to communicate result of asynchronous *computation* from Producer to Consumer(s).
In case of **Future** the *computation* is defined at the time of Future creation and async execution begins "ASAP". It also "knows" how to spawn an asynchronous computation.
In case of **Promise** the *computation*, its *start time* and [possible] *asynchronous invocation* are decoupled from the delivery mechanism. When *computation* result is available Producer must call `deliver` explicitly, which also means that Producer controls *when* result becomes available.  
For **Promises** Clojure makes a design mistake by using the same object (result of `promise` call) to both produce (`deliver`) and consume (`deref`) the result of *computation*. These are two very distinct capabilities and should be treated as such.

Comment: @oskarkv Suppose you've created a promise and gave it to 3 clients. Nothing prevents one of the clients from resolving it with bogus result and signaling it to two other clients. Plus you will not be able to resolve this promise anymore.
In contrast, if you had a promise + resolver pair, gave promise to your clients and kept resolver for yourself this scenario becomes impossible.
For more info suggested search terms are "capability based access control" and "capability based security".

Comment: I'm not sure whether coupling security to a such a simple reference type (check out its impl) as `promise` is would be convenient. 'Evil' consumers are rare; nothing stops you from building your own abstraction on top of promises.

Comment: It's not about security, it just so happens that capability-based programming is often described in relation to security. In here it's all about code correctness. The term often used is "correct by construction" and the question is "can you construct an incorrect program"? Not on purpose, but by accident. With single Promise object you can, while with two separate objects you cannot.

Comment: There's nothing stopping you from returning a promise that can't be delivered though, if that's what you want:

`(defn undeliverable-promise
  []
  (let [p (promise)]
    (reify
      clojure.lang.IDeref
        (deref [_] (deref p))
      clojure.lang.IBlockingDeref
        (deref [_ ms val] (deref p ms val))
      clojure.lang.IPending
        (isRealized [_] (.isRealized p))
      clojure.lang.IFn
        (invoke [_ _] nil))))`

Comment: Pointing out the difference how the computation mechanism is decoupled made this post a really concise explanation. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

There are already excellent answers so only adding the "how to use" summary:

**Both**

Creating promise or future returns a reference immediately. This reference blocks on @/deref until result of computation is provided by other thread.

**Future**

When creating future you provide a synchronous job to be done. It's executed in a thread from the dedicated unbounded pool.

**Promise**

You give no arguments when creating promise. The reference should be passed to other 'user' thread that will `deliver` the result.

Answer (score 1):

In Clojure, `promise`, `future`, and `delay` are promise-like objects. They all represent a computation that clients can await by using `deref` (or `@`). Clients reuse the result, so that the computation is not run several times.

They differ in the way the computation is performed:

- `future` will start the computation in a different worker thread. `deref` will block until the result is ready.
- `delay` will perform the computation lazily, when the first client uses `deref`, or `force`.
- `promise` offers most flexibility, as its result is delivered in any custom way by using `deliver`. You use it when neither `future` or `delay` match your use case.

Answer (score 1):

I think chapter 9 of *Clojure for the Brave* has the best explanation of the difference between `delay`, `future`, and `promise`.

The idea which unifies these three concepts is this: task lifecycle. A task can be thought of as going through three stages: a task is defined, a task is executed, a task's result is used.

Some programming languages (like JavaScript) have similarly named constructs (like JS's `Promise`) which couple together several (or all) of the stages in the task lifecycle. In JS, for instance, it is impossible to construct a `Promise` object without providing it either with the function (task) which will compute its value, or `resolve`ing it immediately with a constant value.

Clojure, however, eschews such coupling, and for this reason it has three separate constructs, each corresponding to a single stage in the task lifecycle.

1. `delay:` task definition
2. `future`: task execution
3. `promise`: task result

Each construct is concerned with its own stage of the task lifecycle and nothing else, thus disentangling higher order constructs like JS's `Promise` and separating them into their proper parts.

We see now that in JavaScript, a `Promise` is the combination of all three Clojure constructs listed above. Example:

```js
const promise = new Promise((resolve) => resolve(6))
```

Let's break it down:

1. task definition: `resolve(6)` is the task.
2. task execution: there is an implied execution context here, namely that this task will be run on a future cycle of the event loop. You don't get a say in this; you can't, for instance, require that this task be resolved synchronously, because asynchronicity is baked into `Promise` itself. Notice how in constructing a `Promise` you've *already* scheduled your task to run (at some unspecified time). You can't say "let me pass this around to a different component of my system and let *it* decide when it wants to run this task".
3. task result: the result of the task is baked into the `Promise` object and can be obtained by `then`ing or `await`ing. There's no way to create an "empty" promised result to be filled out later by some yet unknown part of your system; you *have* to both define the task and simultaneously schedule it for execution.

PS: The separation which Clojure imposes allows these constructs to assume roles for which they would have been unsuited had they been tightly coupled. For instance, a Clojure `promise`, having been separated from task definition and execution, can now be used as a unit of transfer between threads.

Answer (score -4):

Firstly, a `Promise` is a `Future`. I think you want to know the difference between a `Promise` and a `FutureTask`.

A `Future` represents a value that is not currently known but will be known in the future.

A `FutureTask` represents the result of a computation that will happen in future (maybe in some thread pool). When you try to access the result, if the computation has not happened yet, it blocks. Otherwise the result is returned immediately. There is no other party involved in the computing the result as the computation is specified by you in advance.

A `Promise` represents a result that will be delivered by the promiser to the promisee in future. In this case you are the promisee and the promiser is that one who gave you the `Promise` object. Similar to the `FutureTask`, if you try to access the result before the `Promise` has been fulfilled, it gets blocked till the promiser fulfills the `Promise`. Once the `Promise` is fulfilled, you get the same value always and immediately. Unlike a `FutureTask`, there is an another party involved here, one which made the `Promise`. That another party is responsible for doing the computation and fulfilling the `Promise`.

In that sense, a `FutureTask` is a `Promise` you made to yourself.

Comment: Are you Sure A Promise is a Future? i cant find that it implements the interface. https://github.com/richhickey/clojure/blob/a1eff35124b923ef8539a35e7a292813ba54a0e0/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L5489

Comment: sorry, i misspressed enter. My question is changed

Comment: My answer is in a general sense, not in Clojure specific one.

Comment: Answering a question about Clojure with Java code seems a bit whimsical.